# Is there any SQL Query to Order NVARCHR fileds as those(852-2010 ,14-2015 ,20-2011 ,

Tags: crystal-reports

I use Crystal Report and VS 2010 C# I want to order these nvarchar fields as below for example

> 852-2010
>
> 12-2017
>
> 23-2018
>
> 11-2019
>
> 12-2019 . .

Here my code in the button click event

```
string sql3 = " {myTable.Order_date}in #" + StartDate + "# to #" + EndDate + "#"; RptGeneral rpt1 = new RptGeneral(); rpt1.SetParameterValue(0, param); rpt1.RecordSelectionFormula = sql; rpt1.SetDatabaseLogon("cost", "cost"); crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1;
```

Comment: Thank for reply but I still want to sort by this feild not by the date

Answer (score 0):

I believe that best approach her should be order your data from a `DateTime` column in your SQL query, and delivery this data ordered to Crystal Reports.

If you don't have a Date/DateTime column, you should create one.